# My modified, but signed application is still running. Why?

Tags: c#, security, code-signing

Currently I working on a .NET/C# Winforms application. The exe and all dlls are signed. I can view the properties for both kinds of files and verify that my GoDaddy Certificate is both there and valid.

To test the code signing I opened one of the dlls in Notepad++ and modified the file by changing a few characters.

Then I ran the the executable and to my surprise the application still ran! Previously this was not the case.

Since the hash at signing and the hash at execution would be different why is the application still running? Could I not be including a file I need? Could I have a setting wrong?

Comment: You should use strong name assemblies to accomplish what you want.